# APFS - Have I reinstalled MacOS correctly?

Tags: partition, ssd, unix, filesystem, apfs

I tried to dual boot into linux the other day and accidently ended up messaging my boot volume - the machine ended up booting only into Grub resuce.

I ended up using `diskutil` to erase the Linux filesystem and swap memory but was forced to erase my MacOS boot volume. I keep backups of everything so it wasn't a huge problem.

My question is have I reinstalled MacOS (High Sierra this time thanks to internet recovery) in the correct location. As it currently stands I think I've installed it directly onto the disk rather than a volume - is this normal with APFS containers?

Output of `diskutil list` is as follows:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         2.4 GB     disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         248.3 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.4 GB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +248.3 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume MACOS                   15.1 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 22.8 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                506.6 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk2s4
```

Do I need to change anything based on the above disk configuration?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  One question per question, please. Have a look at [help] for questions asking for off site resources.  Especially https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2426/adding-a-close-reason-to-explain-why-recommendations-hardware-book-are-off-to and close reasons.

Comment: So back up everything, completely erase `disk0` from disk utility in OSX recovery? Other than the 2.4GB container, what is it thats improperly formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a useless APFS container with a size of 2.4 GB (disk0s2/disk1) and a second APFS container with a size of 248.3 GB (disk0s3/disk2) with the default set of APFS volumes.

A default install of macOS High Sierra on your internal SSD is expected to look like this:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.7 GB   disk0s2        
/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MACOS                   15.1 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 22.8 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                506.6 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk1s4
```

---

Booted to Internet Recovery Mode or a second boot drive I would completely erase disk0 to one APFS container and either reinstall macOS High Sierra and migrate personal data with the Migration Assistant or restore a current Time Machine backup.

Comment: Thanks for the default layout. I'll crack on with this today.